# Bluestacks installation does not start after extracting

Tags: windows-installation, bluestacks

I downloaded the .exe two times. Once from filehippo and once from the official website. Both are behaving the same way. 
I double click/run as admin then it starts extracting and after that the windows asks me to allow the changes. After clicking OK nothing happens.

I rebooted my system a couple of time. I tried removing temporary files. C: drive have more than enough space free. 8GB RAM. I am installing it as admin and have no virtual machine software installed.

---

I searched for it and I got the following question. But it did not help me because I have more than 100 GB of space free in C: drive.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463012/bluestacks-installation-does-not-start-after-extracting

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out how to install it yet, but if you have 7 zip, just right click and select "extract here." Apparently the built-in file extractor doesn't work. Now to find the installation file. . . look for exe obviously

Answer (score 0):

first download bluestacks 4 then just got to show folder and shift it from the following folder to desktop.Extract it over there, then right click and click 'extract here' the just install bluestacks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still happens and **here's the fix**.

What you need to do is install an older version of BlueStacksX. So if the built in extractor doesn't work in the latest version, it should in an older version. Attached below is a link to an archive of older versions of BlueStacksX. I used 5.8.0 and it worked fine.

[BlueStacksX Archives](https://bluestacks-app-player.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions)